# Errors initialising PySpark installed using pip on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apple-m1

I'm trying to get started with pyspark, but having some trouble. I have python 3.10 installed and an M1 MacBook Pro. I installed pyspark using the command:

```
python3 -m pip install pyspark
```

This seemed to work okay.

```
aaronwright ~ % pyspark --version

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.2.0
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.12.15, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.1
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ubuntu on 2021-10-06T12:46:30Z
Revision 5d45a415f3a29898d92380380cfd82bfc7f579ea
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
Type --help for more information.
```

I also installed Java from here:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

```
aaronwright ~ % java --version

java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Then tried running pyspark with the command:

```
pyspark
```

However I received a number of errors here.

Below is the output. Does anyone have any ideas? There may have a been a configuration step missed as this is the first time I've worked with spark. It could also be an incompatibility somewhere as I'm using a new Mac and new version of Python.

```
aaronwright ~ % pyspark

Python 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:19) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/12/02 16:28:34 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/12/02 16:28:34 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py:42: UserWarning: Failed to initialize Spark session.
  warnings.warn("Failed to initialize Spark session.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession._create_shell_session()  # type: ignore
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 553, in _create_shell_session
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1573, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

EDIT: To get this working, I needed to use Java 8:

`brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Then in my `~/.zshrc` file added the line:

`export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup `JAVA_HOME` and `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` as well. You can download Hadoop from the main website https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/'
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="/Volumes/Work/code/jars/hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*"
```

EDIT #1:
You also might want to downgrade your Java or install another version. This is the official document of installing/setting up Spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html#downloading

> Users can also download a “Hadoop free” binary and run Spark with any Hadoop version [by augmenting Spark’s classpath](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html).

> Spark runs on Java 8/11, Scala 2.12, Python 3.6+ and R 3.5+.

And one more docs about [`pip install pyspark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html)

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't see anything online about setting up `spark_dist_classpath` or installing hadoop. Is this definitely required separately from `pip install pyspark`. The java variable looks fine. But I do have a later version, 17.

Comment: yeah I just updated my answer, give it a shot :)

Comment: Thank you. So I installed Java 8 using `brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8` then in my .zshrc file added the line `export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/'`. Pyspark works now!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue (on my mac). I also have anaconda. I tried unsinstalling the pyspark package from anaconda by executing the following command
conda uninstall pyspark

But it did not remove pyspark completely. While the pyspark bin was gone it left some residual files behind. So I moved the pyspark folder manually and then installed pyspark using the following command

pip install pyspark

After that pyspark is working.